# R: how to extract columns of a matrix with a specific column name?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of two matrices in R, say A and B, stored in mylist object, whose columns are named "1", "1", "10", "13", for the first matrix, and "1", "2", "11", for the second one. I would like to extract the columns of those matrices that are named "1", so the first two columns of matrix A and the first column of matrix B. I tried the following code in R:

`lapply(mylist, function(x) x[, grep("1",colnames(x))] )`

but I get the wrong result: the command selects the columns where "1" appears, so all the columns of A matrix and the first and third columns of B matrix. How can I get the result I'm looking for? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `grep("^1$" , colnames(x))`. Also, maybe better, `colnames(x) %in% "1"`.

Comment: Thank you! Both options worked perfectly!